# What mechanism prevents me from initializing multiple peripherals on the same GPIO pin?

Tags: computer-architecture, hal-library, peripheral

Can I initialize multiple peripherals on the same GPIO pin?

For example, if I bind a GPIO with a peripheral, can I still manipulate this pin with the GPIO interface?

With pseudo-code:

```
spi_init(PORTA, PIN1);
spi_send(/*something*/);

gpio_set(PORTA, PIN1);
```

While my question can seem naive -after all, I could test it easily-, I'm asking it because I want to understand the theory:

- Is there any mechanism that prevents me from initializing multiple peripherals on the same pins?
- What happens on the databus level?

Comment: "*can I still manipulate this pin with the GPIO interface?*" Inadvisable. "*Is there any mechanism that prevents me to initialize multiple peripherals on the same pins?*" Unlikely. It's depending on you not to do something silly.

Comment: Some microcontrollers may have some sort of protection against this, but it will depend on the specific microcontroller. The protection may also be in the compiler--it could throw a compile-time error if you set the same pin in multiple modes at once (though I'm sure there would be ways to do that that the compiler wouldn't notice).

Comment: The multiplexed pins are - that's it, multiplexed. They might be "physically" switched between different peripherals and GPIO (which is kind of peripheral too). So it doesn't really needs a "protection". You can write the GPIO output buffer, but the result won't propagate to the pins, unless the hardware explicitly restricting writing the buffer too in this case.

Comment: That is solely depends on the exact MCU model and how it was engineered (i.e. it's internals). Refer to your MCU documentation for this.

Comment: @NStorm is exactly correct.  Some MCUs configure pin multiplexing from the pin... there's just one alternate function register per pin, so making a connection to a second peripheral overwrites the index of the first peripheral automatically disconnecting it (and you get a related question, what if multiple pins are mapped to the same function?).  In other MCU architectures the multiplexing is configured from the peripheral, and it prevents trying to attach a peripheral's input to multiple pins simultaneously, but you can have multiple peripherals tied to the same pin.

Comment: Having multiple peripheral functions connected to a single pin is sensible and useful if at most one of those functions outputs a signal and the other peripherals are reading it.  Having a single peripheral function mapped to multiple pins is useful for a function outputting a signal.  What you don't want is multiple drivers fighting for control.